# Can't parse .mjs module from Iconify. Vue 3 cli using composition api and typescript

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, babel-loader, webpack-loader

**Update**:
Changing: `if(data.aliases?.[name2] !== void 0)`
to: `if(data.aliases != null && data.aliases[name2] !== void 0)`
in the iconify .mjs file fixes the error, however this check occurs a lot of places, and is not viable. Any idea why I cant parse this type of null operator?

in ./node_modules/@iconify/vue/dist/iconify.mjs

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (99:21)You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

My code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Icon icon="mdi-light:home" />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Icon } from "@iconify/vue";
</script>
```

Iconify version:

```
"@iconify/vue": "^3.2.0"
```

using standard vue cli babel:

```
presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"]
```

I have tried: in babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function override(config) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.mjs$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    type: "javascript/auto"
  });

  return config;
}
```

same error

I tried to remove the .mjs file, forcing it to use regular .js file, this resulted in same error but with missing .js loader.

I have tried to use Iconify SVG framework but i get the same type of error where loader is missing for .js files.

Thanks for any feedback :)

**Solution**:
Downgrading to this version of Iconify `"@iconify/vue": "^3.1.1"` fixed the problem. This resulted however in a error regarding type declaration. This was fixed by changing VS code's typescript version to: `Use workspace version`
This is done by selecting a .ts file then pressing "shift+ctrl+p" and select the prompt of select `typescript version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Downgrading to this version of Iconify `"@iconify/vue": "^3.1.1"` fixed the problem. This resulted however in a error regarding type declaration. This was fixed by changing VS code's typescript version to: `Use workspace version`
This is done by selecting a .ts file then pressing "shift+ctrl+p" and select the prompt of select `typescript version`.

Comment: this is a workaround and not a real solution - in some cases it's not possible to downgrade version unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Having the same error cloning from the repository and install dependencies for Vue 2 https://github.com/iconify/iconify

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).